# Trying to run basic Flutter demo project, but I keep getting a weird error

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to run Flutter's basic demo project in VS Code, but I'm having some trouble. I keep getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x1b1c397f) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x1b1c397f

And I honestly have no idea what it means or how to even start fixing it. Any guidance would be appreciated! Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Make sure that Java is installed without no issues.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?